# Log Rotate doesn't rotate logs

Tags: logrotate, log-rotation

I have a logrotate running on Aws ec2 instance which is trying to rotate logs under /var/log/tomcat8/ every hour. I have below configuration under /etc/logrotate.d/rotate_tomcat:

```
"/var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.*-*-*.txt" "/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.*-*-*.log" "/var/log/tomcat8/agent-log.*-*-*.json" "/var/log/tomcat8/ldap-query-log.*-*-*.*.json" {
    copytruncate
    size 1k
    rotate 5
    compress
    missingok
    create 0644 tomcat tomcat
}
```

When I run this manually, it works as expected. But when I run this as crond, it doesn't do anything. Below is my crond config under /etc/crond.d/accessLogDeletion

`*/2 * * * * root logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/rotate_tomcat`

Any inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with PATH in cron session.

```
/bin/sh: 1: logrotate: not found
```

You can fix with full path of command:

```
*/2 * * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/rotate_tomcat >> /var/log/myCron.log  2>&1
```

or with PATH env at start of cron script:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

*/2 * * * * root logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/rotate_tomcat >> /var/log/myCron.log  2>&1
```

It's a good practice to log output of cron commands like above.